# Joining two tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that share the same column (`C`) but SQL tells me I have an error

Here is the first table from the first query:

```
SELECT   E.C AS C, 
         COUNT(C) AS CC
FROM     E
GROUP BY E.C
```

And here is the second query:

```
SELECT   E.C AS C, 
         COUNT(C) AS Num
FROM     E, G
WHERE    E.G = G.L
         AND G.G <
                    (SELECT min(G.G) 
                     FROM   G
                     WHERE  G.L = "BLAH")

GROUP BY E.C
```

So I tried to simply put these two together by putting `JOIN` in between them. But this doesn't join them, even though they share the same column `C`. It simply says I have a syntax error. What is wrong? And how do I fix it? I have confirmed that when run separately, they produce the correct output with a column `C`

Below is the total `JOIN` execution

```
(SELECT   E.C AS C, 
             COUNT(C) AS CC
    FROM     E
    GROUP BY E.C)

JOIN

(SELECT   E.C AS C, 
             COUNT(C) AS Num
    FROM     E, G
    WHERE    E.G = G.L
             AND G.G <
                        (SELECT min(G.G) 
                         FROM   G
                         WHERE  G.L = "BLAH")

    GROUP BY E.C)
```

And the error is
Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN

```
(SELECT   E.C AS C, 
         COUNT(C) AS Num' at line 6
Line 1, column 1
```

Comment: What error did you receive?  Can you show us the join attempt you made please.  This will help us explain the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show your syntax error but, I am guessing your has to do with the following line:

```
COUNT(C) AS CC
```

Since both tables have a column `C`, the query does not know which table to return the value from. You need to preface it with the table name or alias.

This line works in your first query because you only had one column called `C`, once you have two you need to specify which one you want to return.

Based on your edit, you are missing aliases for the subqueries and the on condition for the join:

```
select t1.C, t1.cc, t2.num
from 
(
    SELECT   E.C AS C, 
             COUNT(C) AS CC
    FROM     E
    GROUP BY E.C
) t1  -- added alias
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT   E.C AS C, 
             COUNT(E.C) AS Num  -- added table name, since column c exists in both tables
    FROM    E 
    JOIN    G
        ON E.G = G.L
    WHERE  G.G < (SELECT min(G.G) 
                   FROM   G
                   WHERE  G.L = "BLAH")
    GROUP BY E.C
) t2  -- added alias
    on t1.C = t2.C  -- added on clause
```

Comment: probably that's the error but we don't have to tolerate people which are so lazy to not post the error generated

Comment: But I am joining on column C...so it makes sense that both tables have Column C

Comment: I did post the error about 3 minutes ago. I wanted to type the error before I typed out the error so that people could start reading it.

Comment: @CodeGuy you were missing aliases on the subqueries and I added a the table name to the second subquery `count(E.C)`

Comment: but now column "C" shows up twice in my output. how do i fix this? it should only show up once

Comment: @CodeGuy instead of `select *`, you will need to specify the columns that you want to return for each query. see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Z.C /*other*/ 
from (SELECT   E.C AS C, 
               COUNT(E.C) AS CC
      FROM     E
      GROUP BY E.C) Z

JOIN (SELECT   E.C AS C, 
             COUNT(E.C) AS Num
       FROM     E, G
       WHERE    E.G = G.L
                AND G.G < (SELECT min(G.G) 
                           FROM   G
                          WHERE  G.L = "BLAH")    
       GROUP BY E.C) Y on Y.C = Z.C
```

Comment: You have to add alias for the column `count(E.C)` in select statement because server doesn't know from which table (E or G) column `C` comes.

Comment: except now column C shows up twice in the output table. How do I fix this? The columns in the output are C, CC, C, Num